# Cache like component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm implementing a cache for the native fetch, and using the latest ReactJS. I was wondering if there was a way to have a global provider or something like that where if a URL exists, just return with the cached data, or if it doesn't, make the call. I dont want to use `redux` because i dont care about state changes, nor do I want to use local/session storage as well, as i do not want to persist on page refreshed. So I was wondering how I could go about doing this?

I would like to import my Fetch wrapper from anywhere in the application and the fetch wrapper calls the cache to check if the call was made. So for the cache i was hoping for it to be a some global component or provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can create a simple class that stores promises internally using urls as keys.

If the stored promise exists you return that and if it doesn't you store a new request promise and return that.

Finally assign a  `new` instance and import that anywhere in your app

```js
class Store {
  constructor() {
    this.store = new Map;
    this.baseUrl = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/'
  }

  getData(path) {
    let message = 'Cached promise'
    const url = this.baseUrl + path
    let promise = this.store.get(url)
    if (!promise) {
      // if url key doesn't exist in map, create and store new promise
      promise = fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
      message = 'New request promise'
      // store this promise using url as key
      this.store.set(url, promise);
    }
    // remove this `then()` and all `message` references in production code
    // just do `return promise`
    return promise.then(data => [data, 'Path : '+ path, message])
  }

}
// export this to use it anywhere in app
const DataStore = new Store();
// export default DataStore

// run multiple times for various paths 
const bins = ['1cvac6', 'exkuu'];
bins.forEach(path => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    DataStore.getData(path).then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
  }
})
```

Note this is only a basic starter and I leave it to you to add error handling

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as this was actually the path that i was going and you cleared it up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good point to know is that a promise object can be used multiple times by calling `then()` at any time on it. To me this is simpler than storing the data itself and having to create a new promise each time vs returning the fetch promise

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement you have to store `pre-fetched` data in your application somehow.

Second way is to use `redux` which you clearly don't want. Third way could be to use `react` own state.

Other way could be to keep the fetched data in an javascript `object` and use that object to check the data. If present return from there. If not fetch data.

Here is suggestion:

```
var cache = {
    `your_url_1`: {},
    `your_url_2`: {}
}
```

You can use this object as following:

```
if (!_.isEmpty(cache[your_url_1])) {
    return cache[your_url_1];
} else {
    var data = fetch(your_url_1);
    cache.your_url_1 = data;

    return data;
}
```

Note: I am using `lodash` `isEmpty` to check if the `cache` already has some data present. `fetch` to get the data from your server.

Comment: The problem with the last way is accessing that cached data from anywhere in the application

Comment: You can have this code in a standalone common file and simply import this wherever you want to use.